# Viewing the HDD activity of active processes

Tags: macos

The [Activity Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor) allows users of Lion to inspect the CPU usage, used memory and some other things for each running process. Unfortunately it doesn't show the drive (IO) activity like e.g. the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) does for Windows.

Is there any tool for OS X that does the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer on another SE site?

https://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x

> From man iotop:
>
> *iotop tracks disk I/O by process, and prints a summary report that is refreshed every interval.*
>
> *This is measuring disk events that have made it past system caches.*
>
> *Since this uses DTrace*, *only the root user or users with the* dtrace_kernel *privilege can run this command.*
>
> This may not be precisely what you want - but it's a ksh script which wraps around dtrace, so you should be able to figure out how to make dtrace do what you need, if iotop doesn't handle it by default.
>
> However, something like iotop -C 5 12 should give you something to start with: it will output 12 samples, each 5 seconds long.